# How to extend OpenFlow menu-like style

Tags: iphone, ipad, coverflow

If you know OpenFlow or CoverFlow, maybe you will have interest for this question.

Latest codes is here  http://github.com/tupps/OpenFlow

What I wanna is make each image as button or menu, click it will enter another view, and also can come back by click some "back" button.

Any clues to implement this feature ?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer my question.

It is quiet easy to do this. There is one delegate API like double tap processing, so just override something there.

Comment: So, do you have an example about it ? 
I would like to see this.